# SSH Public Key Auth doesn't work under clean reinstall of OS X Yosemite

Tags: ssh, macos, openssl

After a clean reinstallation of my MacBook Pro with current Yosemite, the SSH login to all my servers using Public Key auth stopped working.

Generating a new Public Key out of my Private Key and adding it to authorized_keys on the mentioned servers, works. Also using a complete new key is not a problem.

But on some machines that's not an option for me because there is no rescue system available so I can't add the new generated public key.

Output of "ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa ben@hostname -vvv":

```
OpenSSH_6.6, OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/ben/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to foobar.hostname.net [10.1.9.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load ".ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "foobar.hostname.net" from file "/Users/ben/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/ben/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA be:ac:a3:77:60:86:ab:e2:e3:9b:92:02:bc:55:7f:2b
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "foobar.hostname.net" from file "/Users/ben/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/ben/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "10.1.9.1" from file "/Users/ben/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/ben/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'foobar.hostname.net' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/ben/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/ben/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f9cb1c176f0),
debug2: key: .ssh/id_rsa (0x7f9cb1e000c0), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/ben/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: .ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp be:5c:c8:4d:c7:f6:da:e2:82:18:0b:bb:46:56:b5:31
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA be:5c:c8:4d:c7:f6:da:e2:82:18:0b:bb:46:56:b5:31
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '.ssh/id_rsa':
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Output of the in debug3 mode running SSHd:

```
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug1: userauth-request for user ben service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug1: attempt 2 failures 0 [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_key_allowed entering [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 22 [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_key_allowed: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYALLOWED [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 23 [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 22
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 0x7f7218149b50
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug1: trying public key file /home/ben/.ssh/authorized_keys
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug1: matching key found: file /home/ben/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: Found matching RSA key: be:5c:c8:4d:c7:f6:da:e2:82:18:0b:bb:46:56:b5:31
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x7f7218149b50 is allowed
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_key_verify entering [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 24 [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_key_verify: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYVERIFY [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 25 [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 24
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: error: RSA_public_decrypt failed: error:0407006A:lib(4):func(112):reason(106)
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature incorrect
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_answer_keyverify: key 0x7f7218149af0 signature unverified
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 25
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: Failed publickey for ben from 10.1.2.1 port 51104 ssh2
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg ssh-rsa [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey" [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: Connection closed by 10.1.2.1 [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering [preauth]
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug1: do_cleanup
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug1: PAM: cleanup
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering
Dec 31 10:13:02 hostname sshd[23283]: debug1: Killing privsep child 23284
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: Try `chmod 600` on the private key.

Comment: Restore your old key from your backup?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The problem is not, that I don't have the private and public key anymore. They exist and are valid.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I already tried that, without success.

Comment: This is exact issue I am having after clean install of Yosemite. Too bad nobody seems to have answer this this problem.

Comment: `debug3: Could not load ".ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key` Seems to point to the problem. Have you set the correct permissions and ownership on `.ssh/id_rsa`? Is the backup file intact?